# JSON not working with Alamofire 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, alamofire

```
{
    data =     (
        {
             href = "XXX"
             title = "YYY";
        },
        {
            href = "XXX";
            title = "YYY";
        },
      {
            href = "XXX";
            title = "YY";
        }
    );
}


Alamofire.request("http://apps.lowerauf.com.pk/news-app/geo2.php").responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value{
                JSON["data"]["href"]  
            }
        }
```

I am using this code but it's not working and not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` contains `Array` not the `Dictionary`, so you need to loop through the `data` array and then access each nested `JSON` from it.

```
Alamofire.request("http://apps.lowerauf.com.pk/news-app/geo2.php").responseJSON { response in
    //Considering you are using SwiftyJSON
    if let json = JSON(response.result.value) {
        for data in json["data"].arrayValue {
            print(data["href"])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter Can you please care to add the reason for down voting answer, so I will improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Response JSON is `Dictionary` and data is an `array of dictionary` ..

```
   if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any]{
        if let data = json["data"] as? [[String:String]] {
             for value in data {
                 print(value["href"])
             }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

your data is array

```
if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any]{
    if let data = json["data"] as? [[String:String]] {
         for value in data {
             print(value["href"])}
    } }
```